# Flex - get bitmap

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

Is it possible to get the bitmap data from a component using ActionScript?

I dynamically load an image. 
onComplete I create a Flex Image component and add the loaded image to the source

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void 
{
     var image:Image = new Image();
     image.x = 0;
     image.y = 0;
     image.source = e.currentTarget.content;
     canvas.addChild(image); // canvas is already added as an MXML element.
 }
```

Later I want to create a new Image component and get the bitmapData from the first Image.

I have tried this

```
canvas.getChildAt(0)
```

Which seems to give me the Image, but I can not figure out how to get the bitmap data.

```
canvas.getChildAt(0).bitmapData;
```

gives me a compile error "... undefined property"

Does anyone know how ot get the bitmap data so I can use it in my new Image component?

Thanks in advance,

Ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData()

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html

Comment: Thanks, the captureBitmapData did it!

Do you know if it is possible to capture the bitmap without any applied filters?

Answer (score 2):

Cliff's answer will give you a screenshot of the `Image`; to get the underlying BitmapData for the image without doing a screenshot, you can try

```
 Bitmap(image.content).bitmapData
```

This should avoid any filters as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myComponent.width, myComponent.height, true, 0);
bd.draw(myComponent);
```

Comment: Gah, I misread the question as well. Michael is right, my code is for taking screenshots of any old component.